# Настройка прав чтения/записи на виртуальной машине Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm

Всем привет! Начинаю разбираться в linux и виртуалках, поэтому не ругайтесь, пожалуйста :)
Возникла такая проблема. На сервер установил Ubuntu. Далее установил KVM. Сделал виртуальную машину и на этой виртуальной машине с командой Sudo запускаю скрипт. Скрипт скачивает некоторые файлы и потом перемещает их в нужную папку. По при перемещении пишет:
`mv: cannot move '/home/adminvm11/scrypt123.service' to '/etc/systemd/system/scrypt123.service': Permission denied`

Читал уже и про права доступа. Пробовал настроить, но, видимо, не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом или решением :)
уже второй день с этим не могу разобраться

Comment: настройка на виртуальной машине ничем не отличается от физической. Машина не знает, что она виртуальная. Рассказывай что делал и как пробовал. Но вообще, не надо бы в /etc/systemd ничего копировать.

Comment: @Эникейщик вообщем ставлю ноду. раньше это делал на VDS, а сейчас мне отдали физический сервер, вот и копашусь в нём) на арендованной vdsке всё становилось идеально. 
делал следующее: менял права доступа на 775 на папки; запускал скрипт установки от `sudo`